# Call code-behind method from inside html tag?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a C# method called `imageResize` which I can call from the aspx web-form page:

```
<%# imageResize(trustPilot,100,111) %>
// Outputs string
```

But if I try to call it inside an html tag there is no output?

```
<div class="reviews-graphic"  style="background-image: url(<%# imageResize(trustPilot,100,111) %>);"></div>
// No output
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: imageResize returns a data URI?  I think your problem may lie there so please include example output from imageResize

Comment: @ceris did u check my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can add id and runat attributes to div and add style from code behind:

```
<div id="divReviews" runat="server" ...>
....
</div>
```

server side:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        var imgUrl = string.Format("url({0})", imageResize(trustPilot, 100, 111));
        divReviews.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundImage, imgUrl);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
<div class="reviews-graphic"  style='background-image: url(<%# imageResize(trustPilot,100,111) %>);'></div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, still the same - no output